# Hydration object doesn't survive

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've derived my class from `AbstractHydrator` and I'm trying to get the data as follows:

```
public function hydrate (array $data, $object)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $property = $this->getStrategy('default')->hydrate($key);
        $object->$property = $value;
    }
    var_dump($object);
    return $object;
}
```

The `var_dump` returns a valid object with filled values, however, the result (json), created from a `JsonModel` using those returned values returns an array of `null`s in quantity equal to table rows.

Here's my factory config:

```
'UserTableGateway' => function  ($sm)
{
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $hydrator = new \Core\Hydrator\TableEntityMapper();
    $hydrator->addStrategy('default', new UserNamingStrategy());
    $resultSet = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet(
            $hydrator, new User());
    return new TableGateway('users', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSet);
}
```

What should I do for the `$object` to survive the return? It works perectly well for instance when I try using the `ClassMethods` hydrator with getters and setters, so I assume that the problem lies in this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to other `ViewModel`s, but something obvious struck me at some point.

Namely, `JsonModel` needs both `hydrate`, in order to populate objects when getting data, as well as `extract`, as `JsonModel` requires an `array`, methods implemented.

If you fail to deliver an implementation of `extract`, your objects will be returned in an `array` in their raw form and `JsonModel` will convert each of them to a `null` object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the 'hydration strategy' rather than the 'naming strategy' for the `$property` value.

The confusion is understandable, however to be clear, 'naming strategies' are used to modify the target objects property *name* and the 'strategies' are used to modify the given field's *value*.

Firstly, change the factory and use the `AbstractHydrator`'s `setNamingStrategy()` method instead.

```
'UserTableGateway' => function  ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

    $hydrator = new \Core\Hydrator\TableEntityMapper();

    // UserNamingStrategy should be of type NamingStrategyInterface
    $hydrator->setNamingStrategy(new UserNamingStrategy());

    $resultSet = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet($hydrator, new User());

    return new TableGateway('users', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSet);
}
```

Then update the hydrator to check for both a naming strategy and the hydration value strategy and apply them if found. The `AbstractHydrator` has convenience methods [`hydrateName`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/AbstractHydrator.php#L172) and [`hydrateValue`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/AbstractHydrator.php#L141) to do so.

```
public function hydrate (array $data, $object)
{
    foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
        $property = $this->hydrateName($name);

        // $data is optionally passed in as context
        $object->$property = $this->hydrateValue($name, $value, $data);
    }
    return $object;
}
```

You will of course be able to do the inverse to this with `extract()`.